# How to quickly deploy a Aiohttp Python project on Heroku or similar

Tags: python, heroku, aiohttp

I've got an aiohttp based project in Python, not overly complicated, just takes advantage of the async routes, etc. I'd like to quickly deploy to Heroku and cannot find a recent step by step. I've tried using their standard Gunicorn approach and it's not working. My Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn go:web --preload
```

Here are the errors that seem to be important from my Heroku log:

```
2020-06-28T01:37:40.103872+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========
2020-06-28T01:37:40.103895+00:00 app[web.1]: (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-06-28T01:37:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-28T01:38:31.441039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

If anyone has successfully deployed an aiohttp project to Heroku, I'd love to know what you had to adjust to get it working!  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for a hello world aiohttp app

here's `app.py`

```
from aiohttp import web
import os


async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])


web.run_app(app, port=os.getenv('PORT'))
```

Procfile
`web: python app.py --bind localhost:8080`

requirements.txt

```
aiohttp
Flask
Werkzeug
```

Thankful for this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439912/deploy-aiohttp-on-heroku) which help alot for not using gunicorn.

BAMN!

[image]