# Deploy aiohttp web server on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, aiohttp

I'm trying to deploy a really simple aiohttp app to heroku, here's `main.py` file:

```py
import os
from aiohttp import web

routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/')
async def handle(request):
    return web.Response(text='Welcome')


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ['PORT'])
    web.run_app(app, port=port)
```

And here's the `Procfile`

```
web: python main.py
```

It works fine in localhost, but when I upload it to heroku I get:

```
 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=******.herokuapp.com request_id=4e96418b-04bc-4bbb-bd4f-2b17320c3bc7 fwd="81.61.104.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439912/deploy-aiohttp-on-heroku) question didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line should help here, just try:

```
web.run_app(app, port=os.getenv('PORT'))
```

Instead of

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ['PORT'])
    web.run_app(app, port=port)
```